# Minecraft pocket edition restoring skin problem

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I updated Minecraft PE so I can have custom skins. I clicked on 'restore skins' without selecting any particular skin, It is now stuck with a  message saying 'we're restoring your skins!' but it has been like that for 20 minutes. Is there a reason why it is like this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the "Restore Skins" button is used if you have previously purchased skins but the app is showing that you still need to buy it. You don't need to press it if you just want to apply a skin.

- To get out of the "We're restoring skins" message, close the app. Don't just press the home button, make sure it's actually closed.
- Open the app again and tap the skin you want. The free ones don't have a padlock symbol next to them.
- Press Back. Your skin should be applied.
- You can check your skin by switching to third person or by tapping the armor icon inside your inventory.